# ASP.Net MVC 5 EF6 - Allow nullables on two properties but force at least one to be present

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In simple relational terms, I want each entry of ContractDetails to be assigned to either a Site OR a Company, not both at the same time, and one of them must be selected or there is no link at all. I'm not quite sure how to represent this in entity framework. My Model at Present:

Company Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }
    public string Company_Prefix { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }

}
```

Contract Details Model:

```
public class ContractDetails
{
    public int ContractDetailsID { get; set; }

    public int ContractTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ContractRenewalPeriodID { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int? SiteID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contract Start Date"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Contract_Start_Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contract End Date"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Contract_End_Date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public string Direct_Debit_Reference { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual ContractType ContractType { get; set; }
    public virtual ContractRenewalPeriod ContractRenewalPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Site Model:

```
public class Site
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Site_Name { get; set; }
    public string Site_TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Site_City { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement the [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) on `ContractDetails` class. On `Validate` method put the validation logic. If the object is not valid you must return a collection of `ValidationResult`. when saving the object, EF will execute the `Validate` method and verify that your  `ContractDetails`  object is coherent.